# How to set and reuse source code on android

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I'm having to trouble on developing Android apps. I want to reuse this section many other activities. And I found "layout inflater". Moreover I can use that.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <!-- Header Start -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="#fff8f8ff">

        <!-- Menu button -->
        <Button
             android:id="@+id/menuBtn"
             android:layout_width="40dp"
             android:layout_height="30dp"
             android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
             android:background="@drawable/menubtn"/>

        <!-- Logo / Return to Main page -->
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/logoBtn"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

        <!-- Login Btn -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/logoBtn"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- End of Header -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

**But, Now! I am having a problem to next step. How to set and reuse activity that is button listener and like that.**

```
    // header button listener
    Button menuBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.menuBtn);
    Button logoBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.logoBtn);
    Button loginBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);

    menuBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    logoBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "logo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    // End of header Button
```

I want reuse that section to other activities. And I am trying to import system but, I do not yet.

Shortly, I want to reuse source code(listener and xml). How can I do that?

Comment: Create a base `Activity` that implements common functions (listeners, menu, etc), and use it to extend other activities.

Comment: Thank you your comment. You means that using inheritance? But, in this case, where can I implement common listener? If I extend parents class , then I modify onCreate() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements Button.OnClickListener{  
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            menuBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
            logoBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
            loginBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
 }
 public void onClick(View v) {
   if(menuBtn == v)  {
      showMyToast("menu");
   }else if(logoBtn == v){
      showMyToast("logo");
  }else if(loginBtn == v){
      showMyToast("login");
  }
 } 

private void showMyToast(String str){
    Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} 
}
```

Comment: Thanks tianwei. Is it okay to extend other activities? Like I above mentioned, when I inheritance activity I am reuse onCreate() function. And I think that each button will have each function.

Comment: You can make a BaseActivity as mentioned. Other activity who extend the BaseActivity will be able to use these base methods.If you want to override them and use the logic of BasicActivity,just use super.xxx();(eg. super.showMyToast(str)).

Comment: Okay, I am now confused android(and java) versus other language. Thank you!